# What was the command that was entered for this iptables rule

Tags: centos, iptables

So I have some rules on my server for my VPN, but my partner does port forwarding if needed for my customers. I want to know how to do it myself but he doesn't want to tell me. Now I found these rules on my server, could anyone translate it to the command that was entered? Like the command my partner typed in putty to add this rule, so I can learn from it.

If possible explain what everything does aswell please :).

Picture of rules:

[image: http://img211.imageshack.us/img211/8536/f47067ed35ff487c97db0bf.png]

Comment: You have a serious problem with your partner, and it has nothing to do with iptables rules.

Comment: Then how did he manage to port forward these ports?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you do

```
iptables-save > iptables.txt
```

Will get the iptables commands, you will need to add iptables in front of them to add just the one line

You can use

```
iptables-restore < iptables.txt
```

to restore the iptables rules as they are in the in files.
This is useful for backups before changing things.

Answer (score 0):

Read up the iptables man page to see what each switch/flag does.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 1338 -j DNAT --to 10.8.1.1:1338
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 777 -j DNAT --to 10.8.1.1:777
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 1122 -j DNAT --to 10.8.1.1:1122
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 1124 -j DNAT --to 10.8.1.1:1124
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 1604 -j DNAT --to 10.8.1.1:1604
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 3030 -j DNAT --to 10.8.1.1:3030
```

Comment: The other answer by Epaphus is better; it will allow you to find the commands for any other rules too. Of course, learning it properly is still even better though.